# What does this OpenCV installation error mean and how can I resolve it?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

My system is Ubuntu 14.04.
I tried many several methods to install OpenCV (tried both 2 and 3). I can not successfully install.

I followed [this documentation][1] for the installation and got this error.

**UPDATE:**

I reinstalled ffmpeg and x264. I have tried almost all the blogposts and official docs. This is the error I find:

**UPDATE 2:**

Please find the new error again [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOiRC.png)

**UPDATE 3:**

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to reinstall OpenCV but it did not help. Find the error here:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:256: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6364: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Your picture actually shows only the number of errors but none of the error descriptions.

Comment: @QuangHoang Please find the new image. I have been trying to install since last two days. I have followed almost all blogposts and tutorials.

Comment: It says `libavcodec` is missing. Did you install it?

Comment: No. I did install ffmpeg. How can I install 'libavcodec'? I just find libavcodec-dev

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libavcodec*`

Comment: Nope. Some error. Please find  [here](http://imgur.com/a/RsP3O)

Comment: If I do without * then this is the error: sudo apt-get install libavcodec
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libavcodec

Comment: It looks like you already have `libavcodec` installed. You may want to symlink `libavcodec.so.54` to `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Okay. Is this correct? I tried this: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib libavcodec.so.54`

Comment: It's the other way around: `sudo ln -s /path/to/libavcodec.so /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54`. You need to find the path to `libavcodec.so` or the similar though.

Comment: Okay. Done. Now, what would you recommend to install opencv again? Should I delete all the files and reinstall? Please refer me to the good installation link

Comment: It's a good guide already. Just try `cmake ..` and `make` again. If you have gui on your Ubuntu, I recommend using `cmake-gui` instead of `cmake` in terminal.

Comment: @QuangHoang Please find the error in update 2.

Comment: Please Follow this tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @ZdaR I did follow that. But, it is still not working. I also upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS just for OpenCV installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some dependencies which did not allow the system to install. I followed almost all tutorials. I could easily install OpenCV2/3 with `conda`.

Answer (score 0):

`libavcodec-dev` was [discontinued](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavcodec-dev) since trusty (14.04), and FFmpeg replaced it. Having said that, building opencv from source still requires this and some other deprecated libraries. (You might need to search in other repositories, look only for official ones). I noticed this error when I followed the [same method](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/) of building opencv from source on Linux Mint 19 and Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome. 
You might also want to re-clone/download the opencv repository from GitHub and `git checkout 3.4.1` or higher.